# Is my red eared slider eggbound?

Tags: health, turtles

My female red eared slider has been showing signs that she wants to lay eggs for the past week, with a small appetite, wanting to leave her home, and is constantly digging with her legs. Because of this, I've moved her to the kitchen where she has laid a few eggs underneath a rack last year. However, a week has gone by and although she exhibits digging motion, she hasn't laid any eggs.

Yesterday (this is what worries me) she has completely stopped trying to leave her home, does not exhibit digging motions when she is let out, and has a large appetite. It's like she's given up on trying to lay eggs. On top of that she looks slightly depressed and bites people to try to touch her, which is irregular. I'm worried that she has failed to find a proper nest and has decided to keep them, in other words egg-binding which I've discovered whilst searching the net.

Should I be worried and take her to a vet? Or should I wait a while to see if she wants to lay eggs again, and prepare a proper nesting area for her?

Comment: I'm sorry for answering so late but has she laid eggs yet?